# IE Document Mode is set to 11 in compatibility mode but it doesn't render the way IE11 does

Tags: css, internet-explorer, tomcat, liferay

My page renders correctly in IE11 with compatibility mode off.  With compatibility mode on it renders incorrectly.  I have attempted to coerce IE into document mode 11 in the following ways:

1) Using the META tag:
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

2) Setting a key/value in the HTTP response header: X-UA-Compatible/IE=edge

In both cases the document.documentMode attr in IE reads as 11 even when compatibility mode is on.  However, it will still render incorrectly.

Does anyone know what is going on?  It seems I've successfully instructed IE to use IE11 mode in multiple ways.  I know IE11 mode works for my page because there isn't a problem in IE11 with compatibility mode off.

In case it matters, I'm using Liferay Portal 6.1.20 EE.

Comment: If it renders fine without resorting to compatibility mode, what is the problem?

Comment: We have to ask users to place IE in compatibility mode in order to use other apps on our domain.  IE defaults to wildcarding your domain.  That means we would have to ask users to edit the path in their IE compatibility mode settings.  That's very undesirable as many users will likely get it wrong.

Comment: Actually, it looks like domain is the smallest level of granularity IE allows.

Comment: And upgrading those other apps so that they no longer require compatibility mode is not an option? In that case, you will have to take a look at the webpage itself. There is no general solution, no magic bullet that will let a page behave the same way in compatibility mode as in standard mode. The only thing I can say is, check if there aren't any errors; errors will probably be handled differently in compatibility mode. You do have a proper DOCTYPE declaration, right?

Comment: Thanks for your input, it's appreciated.  I would like to point out, in case someone reads this and can help, that I'm not looking for a magic bullet.  My page renders properly in IE11 document mode.  The problem is that IE isn't rendering it with IE11 document mode, rather it's rendering in IE7 mode.  This is despite the fact that the browser reports IE11 mode.  If it were truly using IE11 mode then the page would render correctly.  That belief is predicated by the fact the page works perfectly fine when compatibility mode is off in IE11.